# Unblocking all the assembly files in a folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I have downloaded a sample windows mobile app from the net and it's just  a normal folder , not a zipped one. When I try to run it on VS 2010 express edition for windows phone it says the assembly may have been loaded from the web, it is flagged by windows as a web file. You can change the designation by changing the properties, Unlock all the assemblies that you trust. How do I do this? Should I go to each of the files in my folder and do the unblock thing or should I do it on any particular file?

Answer (score 5):

Since it is not a zip file you will have to go to each file and unblock it. If you select multiple files it will not give you the unblock option.

[image]